# Extract data from stored procedure to existing excel file

Tags: sql-server, excel

I got simple stored procedure which get some result, at the end I want this data update in existing excel file, the excel file will have already some data so solution needs to insert data without removing previous record.

```
USE [My_Db]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 -- =============================================
 -- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Analysed_Data] 
 @db_name    varchar(100),
 @table_name varchar(100),   
 @file_name  varchar(100)
AS
 BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

 select 
        customer.[Land Description]
       ,customer.[Owner name]
 FROM    [My_Db].[dbo].[CustomerList$] AS customer

END
```

Comment: You would be better off doing this in SSIS, Powershell or a programming language. Even possibly a macro in your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what version of Excel you are using and what your limitations are, you may be able to use Power Pivot in Excel.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.